# Power BI- Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to import data from SSAS but I keep receiving the below error in Power Bi:

**Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] AnalysisServices: There's not enough memory to complete this operation. Please try again later when there may be more memory available.. '.**